# node-tesseract failed to load languages

Tags: javascript, node.js, ocr, tesseract

I copied a code from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63297615/14911094) to read text from a base64 of an image:

```
let base64 = req.body.toString("base64");
let imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");

const worker = createWorker();
(async () => {
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
    await worker.initialize('eng');
    console.log("Recognizing...");
    const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(imageBuffer);
    console.log("Recognized text:", text);
    await worker.terminate();
})();
```

But I a getting this Error:

```
Error opening data file ./eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Recognizing...
AdaptedTemplates != nullptr:Error:Assert failed:in file /workspace/tesseract/src/classify/adaptmatch.cpp, line 196
undefined
undefined
C:\Users\jaysm\OneDrive\Desktop\QBase\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:173
        throw Error(data);
        ^

Error: RuntimeError: abort(undefined). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jaysm\OneDrive\Desktop\QBase\node_modules\tesseract.js\src\createWorker.js:173:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:903:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What is the problem with my code?

I found some solutions of this error but they were with python or some other languages but none with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my problem was not of setting `TESSDATA_PREFIX` as environment variable but i had not placed the `eng.traineddata` file in the base directory.

I placed the `eng.traineddata` file and the issue was resolved!

Comment: What do you mean by base directory? I have `eng.traineddata` next to the `index.js` and in the directory I run `node index.js` from and I still get this error.

Comment: did you install tesseract for your os (not the node-tessaract but for windows) see https://medium.com/quantrium-tech/installing-and-using-tesseract-4-on-windows-10-4f7930313f82